# Specify a named graph when inserting tripple using RDF/XML

Tags: rdf, graphdb, rdf-xml

I am using RDF/XML to insert tripples in a tripplestore (GraphDb).
This works but I also need all tripples are gathered into a unique named graph and I am looking for the right syntax in RDF/XML to do this, when inserting data and always using the same name for the graph (something as "http://domain_com/graphName").

The only documentation I found is this one https://www.w3.org/2009/07/NamedGraph.html#rdf-xml but I only get errors when trying to implement it, I must confess I am not a RDF/XML specialist ...

Can somebody provide  an explicit example ?

Answer (score 4):

RDF/XML syntax does not support named graphs (the document you found is more about graph literals, which is a separate concept, and also, AFAIK, has never taken beyond a draft proposal).

If you wish to add RDF data to a named graph in GraphDB, you will either need to specify the named graph separately from the data file (as an extra argument to the upload command), or you will need to switch to using a different RDF syntax format that *does* support named graphs. [TriG](https://www.w3.org/TR/trig/) or [N-Quads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Triples#N-Quads) are commonly used and widely supported formats for this.